# Extremum under variations of a traceless matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, traces, calculus-of-variations

Sorry for my precedent tentative, I was a little hasty:

Ok, I think I'd better put the original problem:

I have an action of three fields: $A$ which is the spin-connection, $B$ an skew-symmetric 2-form and $\Phi$ which is traceless <s>and skew-symmetric</s> scalar field. These fields take their values on some algebra, index their components in this algebra by $i,j,k,... = 1,2,3$

I want to implement a certain condition on B by using equations of motion of $\Phi$, the action is:

$S=\int (B_i \wedge F^i + \Lambda B_i \wedge B^i + \Phi_{ij} B^i \wedge B^j) $

Now for me equations of motions are simply:

$B^i \wedge B^j=0$

perhaps with the condition that all diagonal elements are equal (as jc showed) <s>but this is automatically satisfied for a skew-symmetric matrix (here $B^i \wedge B^j$)</s>.

But in all papers I find:

$B^i \wedge B^j - \frac{1}{3}\delta^{ij}B_k\wedge B^k = 0$

So I see that they all took the traceless part of the matrix representing equations of motion, necessarily it has a relation with the traceless character of $\Phi$ but I do not see which one.

<s>In addition, this expression is not antisymmetric in $i,j$</s>.

Would anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B^i$ are 2-forms, then $B^i \wedge B^j$ is symmetric, not skewsymmetric.  Since $\Phi_{ij}$ is traceless, only the traceless part of $B^i \wedge B^j$ that couples to $\Phi$.  So I see nothing wrong with the equation you find in the papers.

The reason you take $\Phi$ to be traceless is that the trace is already contained in the second term in the action.

---

**Edit** (in response to the comment thread below)

Let me give more details.  Let $M^{ij} := B^i \wedge B^j$.  We can think of $M$ as a matrix with 4-forms as entries.  The space of even forms is a commutative algebra, so we can work with $M$ as if it were a real or complex matrix, say.  In particular, we can take its trace (which will be a 4-form): $T = \delta_{ij} M^{ij}$, where as in the question the Einstein summation convention is in force.  We can then decompose $M$ into a traceless part we shall call $M_0$ and a part containing the trace:
$$M^{ij} = M_0^{ij} + \frac{1}{N} T \delta^{ij},$$
where I assume that $M$ is an $N\times N$ matrix.  If you take the trace of this equation, you find that $M_0$ is indeed traceless.  Its explicit form is given by solving that equation for $M_0$, but we do not need it.

Now let $\Phi_{ij}$ be a symmetric traceless matrix.  This means that $\delta^{ij} T_{ij} = 0$.  Contracting with $M$ we find
$$\Phi_{ij} M^{ij} = \Phi_{ij} M_0^{ij}.$$
In other words, $\Phi$ never sees the trace of $M$ and hence if you have a lagrange multiplier term in an action functional of the form
$$\int \Phi_{ij} M^{ij}$$
this is really equal to
$$\int \Phi_{ij} M_0^{ij}$$
and hence the resulting Euler-Lagrange equation is $M_0^{ij} = 0$.

Comment: I was wrong about `$B^i \wedge B^j$` sorry.

"Since `$\Phi_{ij}$` is traceless, only the traceless part of `$B^i \wedge B^j$` that couples to `$\Phi$`": I thought about that, In the same way as an antisymmetric tensor kills the symmetric part of a tensor contracted with it... But when I tried this on a concrete example it didn't work!

Comment: What concrete example?  If you write $B^i \wedge B^j$ in the action as  $(B^i \wedge B^j)_0$, say, which is traceless, and a trace part, then the third term does not see the trace part.  hence the equation of motion of $\Phi$ cannot possibly set all of $B^i \wedge B^j$ to zero, only $(B^i \wedge B^j)_0$.

Comment: I think that when one says traceless it is not necessarily "all diagonal element vanishing"... 

Comment: if all diagonal elements of `$\Phi$` are zero it's ok, one keep only the traceless part of `$B^i \wedge B^j$`... Perhaps what all these authors wanted to say by traceless is "all diagonal elements" :-s

Comment: Traceless does not of course mean "all diagonal elements", just their sum.  Take a symmetric $N \times N$ matrix $M_{ij}$ (in your case valued in 2-forms...) and decompose it into traceless and trace as follows: $M_{ij} = (M_{ij} - \frac{1}{N} \delta_{ij} t) + \frac{1}{N} \delta_{ij} t$, with $t$ the trace.  Then contracting with $\Phi$, you find that because $\Phi$ is traceless, meaning $\Phi_{ij} \delta_{ij} = 0$ (Einstein summation), the trace part gives zero.

Comment: Yep I tried this but if you do `$\Phi_{ij} \delta^{ij}$` for the third term why not for the second also??

Comment: If you did that, you would not learn anything since you get the identity that $\Phi_{ij} M_{ij} = \Phi_{ij} M_{ij}$.  I think that I will edit my answer giving more details.

Comment: alright! I got it :-)

 What you wrote was actually the first thing I thought and even wrote, but I don't know... when I saw that the second term vanishes when contracting with `$\Phi$` I doubted... So I did some example but my problem was that I was taking the traceless part of a matrix as the same matrix with all diagonal elements zero in my examples!!!  How stupid!!!

Neverthless, the vanishing of the trace-part of the matrix is not so abvious that say, the vanishing of the skew-symmetric part... at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

**[MOD: this is an answer to a previous version of the question]**

I'm not sure I believe your answer.  Perhaps I'm missing something though.

Let $T = X_{ij}Y^{ij} + \lambda (X_{ij}\delta^{ij})$, which is your original function plus a [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers) for the traceless constraint.

Extremize by setting partial derivatives with respect to the entries $X_{ij}$ to zero:

$0=\frac{\partial T}{\partial X_{ij}}=Y^{ij}+\lambda \delta^{ij}$

For entries where $i=j$, this is $Y^{ii}+\lambda =0$, which yields the condition that all diagonal entries of $Y$ are equal, not that $Y$ is traceless.  For the entries with $i\neq j$, we recover $Y^{ij}=0$ as usual.

Comment: Yep; seen like that you're right... The problem is that in all papers I read it is my first answer that appears!! (of course we have a real action ie: a functional, does it change something?)

Comment: what if `$X$` and `$Y$` are skew-symmetric?

Comment: Well if they are skew-symmetric, they are automatically traceless since their diagonal entries must be zero.  I suspect that things may become a little clearer if you update your question with a more realistic functional that you're interested in.